# Is it possible to send data from a client to a server without the API being public?

Tags: flask, rest

I'm currently trying to make an account signup page for a small project I'm working on and I don't know how to send data back to the server (I'm using the Flask framework) without also allowing everyone to send data. Let's say that I've set up an API endpoint on `/createAccount`. I can then send POST requests to that endpoint: `{"username": "test", "password": "test"}`. The web server will then handle that request by  inserting that data into a database and responding with `201`. The problem is, anybody would be able to send these requests, and I only want users to be able to register through the login page, and not by making an API call. Is there any way of doing this?

Edit: I've given this problem a bit more thought and I think that the only API that is difficult to secure is the signup API. When a user has created an account, I can just assign them an API key, which they will send to the API every time they want to make a request, which means that an account is required to make API calls. If a certain key is making too many requests, they can be rate limited or temporarily banned from making further requests. The problem with the signup API however, is that there is no information by witch a request sender could be identified. I could use the IP address, but that can be changed and wouldn't really help if multiple IPs are spamming the API at the same time. Is there a way I can identify non-registered users?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

You have to check data to make sure the account being created is something legit and not trash data to fill your database or any other malicious intents.

This is the reason you usually have to confirm an account clicking on a confirmation link sent to your mail: this way the app is sure that your account is legit.

You could also check info on the front end, but that is never as secure as back end checking, because of your concern in the question: in the end, anyone who gets to know your endpoints could potentially send direct requests to your server with whatever data they wanted.

Comment: Ok. Is there any other way to send data back to the server?

Comment: No. Once the user has authenticated, you can block certain parts of the api so it responds only to authenticated users. But your concern being about the user creation endpoint, I'm afraid there's no way to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a trusted source of registrations, an if that source can make an ssh connection to the server where your Flask app is running, an alternative to trying to lock down a registration API is to provide a command line script to do the registration.

The trusted source does something like

```
ssh someuser@youripaddress /path/to/register.py "username" "password" "other info"
```

If you use a Flask [custom command](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#custom-commands) you can share model definitions db configuration.